# Null source create empty object for destination

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I am using automapper 7.0.1 with .Net core 2.1.

This class converts to

```
public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int? CurrencyId { get; set; }

    public Location Location { get; set; } = null;
}

public class ItemLocation 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Translation Translations { get; set; }

    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; } = false;                 

    public IList<ItemLocationUserDefined> UserDefinedItemLoacation { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public float Latitude { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Converts to :

```
public class ItemsToReturnDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int? CurrencyId { get; set; }

    public LocationDto Location { get; set; } = null;
}

public class ItemLocationToReturnDto
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public Translation Translations { get; set; }

        public float Latitude { get; set; }

        public float Longitude { get; set; }

        public bool IsUserDefined { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    }
```

I have initialized Automapper in startup.cs

```
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
    mc.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
    mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
});

IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Mapping profile :

```
CreateMap<ItemsToReturnDto, Item>()
                .ForMember(dest => (int)dest.Status, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Status))
                .ReverseMap();
CreateMap<ItemLocationToReturnDto, ItemLocation>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.IsPrivate, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.IsUserDefined))
                .ReverseMap();
```

But even if source Location object is null Automapper automatically initialize empty Location object.

How I can return null if source is null?

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: I would have to create a whole project in order to share complete code.

Comment: No, you just have to do the work to isolate the issue. That might be difficult, but it would prove the problem is with AM, not with your own code.

Comment: You need to add the classes `Location`, `LocationDto` and `MappingProfile`, without these there is not enough to look at this properly as no one can reproduce it

Comment: @matt_lethargic sorry for late response but code added.

Comment: The code supplied is not correct, there is no `Item.Status` property that is in the mapping profile, `Item.Location` uses type `Location` that does not exist. `ItemsToReturnDto.Location` uses type `LocationDto` that does not exist

Comment: I've created a test based on the code example given, but I cannot replicate the issue, this leads me to believe that there is more at play here and you haven't been able to isolate the code correctly that would produce this issue see my gist https://gist.github.com/matt-lethargic/735b2edf44b687f8ce5e490484ddb296

Comment: @Epistemologist have you solved the issue? I face the same and cant null the target any other way than setting .Ignore() for the member.

Comment: haha, looks like `.Ignore()` is the only workaround. [Ignore by default and then set the value manually where needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354104).  a kind of semi"auto"mapping