# How to configure Automapper 9 to ignore Object-Properties if object is null but map if not null

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I´ve tried a lot, but I can´t find what I´m really looking for. This is my case: I have an EF-Core entity with navigation-properties and a viewModel:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual NestedObject NestedObject { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEntityViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string NestedObjectStringValue { get; set; }
    public int NestedValueIntValue { get; set; }
}
```

This is my CreateMap which creates a new NestedObject even if no NestedObject-Property is set (Condition doesn´t seem to apply here):

```
CreateMap<SomeEntityViewModel, SomeEntity>(MemberList.Source)
        .ForPath(m => m.NestedObject.StringValue, opt =>
        {
            opt.Condition(s => s.Destination.NestedObject != null); 
            opt.MapFrom(m => m.NestedObjectStringValue);
        });
```

This avoids Creating a new NestedObject if Properties are null but if not, the NestedObject Properties are not mapped:

```
CreateMap<SomeEntityViewModel, SomeEntity>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(m => m.NestedObject, opt => opt.AllowNull());
```

Second CreateMap doesn´t Map NestedObject-Properties if they are set, first creates a new NestedObject if the Properties are not set. But both together are not working. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Don't use `ReverseMap` then. Create the reverse map explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `ReverseMap()` ,then try to use AutoMapper [Conditional Mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html#conditional-mapping) and use `ForPath` instead of `ForMember` for nested child object properties:

```
CreateMap<SomeEntityViewModel, SomeEntity>()
    .ForPath(
            m => m.NestedObject.StringValue, 
            opt => {                         
                     opt.Condition(
                        s => s.DestinationMember != null && s.DestinationMember != "" 
                     );
                     opt.MapFrom(s => s.NestedObjectStringValue);
                   }
            );
```

The same to `IntValue`.

**Update**

So, if the `NestedObject` is null, you do not want to to map the value from `SomeEntityViewModel` to it. If the `NestedObject` is not null,mapping works.

Please refer to below code which uses `AfterMap`

```
CreateMap<SomeEntityViewModel, SomeEntity>()
             .ForMember(q => q.NestedObject, option => option.Ignore())
             .AfterMap((src, dst) => {
                     if(dst.NestedObject != null)
                     {
                     dst.NestedObject.StringValue = src.NestedObjectStringValue;
                     }

                 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I‘ll try this asap

Comment: I want to check NestedObject for null. Your solution checks NestedObject.StringValue, which is not needed. I´ve updated my question to explain better what I´m trying to achieve.

Comment: @Joshit You could get `NestedObject`  by using `s.Destination.NestedObject `,try  `opt.Condition(s => s.Destination.NestedObject != null);`.Not sure it will work..

Comment: That doesn´t work either. I´ve updated my question again - sorry! It is hard to describe what I want exactly as I´m not a native speaker

Comment: @Joshit I update my code and hope it is useful.if it is still not you want,could you write some examples of input and result of the mapping to make it clear?

Comment: thats what I need. thank you very much for your patience and the time spent on this! You really helped a lot with this!!!

Comment: @Ryan you are the hero! Found myself that only Ignore works where any conditional expressions do not, but setting the value manually `.AfterMap` was really a great finding! I was about to do the same outside the "automapping". There were several attempts on github to report this bug, but all missed some essential details and have been closed without enough attention.